# Subtract List B from List A but keeping the List A index

Tags: python, list, count

I need some help with Python
This is not the classic subtract List B from List A to make List C
Instead I would like to look at the indexes of the items in List A that are not in List B, and store them into a new List C.

e.g.

```
List A:
0. car
1. plane
2. truck
3. motorcycle
4. jet
5. train

List B:
0. plane
1. jet
```

So, the result should be...

```
List C:
0.
2.
3.
5.
```

The result items are not important (car, truck, motorcycle, train), instead I need to keep the original indexes of the items in List A, once the subtraction has been made.
What is the fastest simplest way to do this in Python?
Thanks Advanced

Comment: What is the Python way you have tried?

Comment: Python's list indexes start with `0`, not `1`

Comment: `[k for k,v in enumerate(A) if v not in B]`

Comment: `[k for k,v in enumerate(A, start=1) if v not in B]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
a = ["car", "plane", "truck", "motorcycle", "jet", "train"]
b = ["plane", "jet"]
c = [i for i, v in enumerate(a, start=1) if v not in b]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [index for index,value in enumerate(A, start=1) if value not in B]
```